# SQL Case Statement to Evaluate multiple values in one column

Tags: sql, case

I have a table that store the customer's 'PreOrder' number and 'PostOrder' number in the same column. I'm trying to write a case statement that will evaluate if the patient has one of the 'PreOrder' number and/or the 'PostOrder' number. There are three different numbers that could represent a 'PreOrder' and two different numbers that will represent a 'PostOrder'.
If the customer has one of the 'PreOrder' numbers, I will like to return 'Pre'.
If the customer has one of the 'PostOrder' numbers, I will like to return 'Post'.
If a customer has one of the 'PreOrder' numbers and one of the 'PostOrder' numbers, I will like to return 'BothOrders'.
Here is my query...

```
SELECT 
   Cust.Cust_ID 
 , CASE WHEN Cust.Order_ID in ('154','3042000103','3042000099') THEN 'PreOrder'
        WHEN Cust. Order_ID in ('30400010112','3042000104') THEN 'PostOrder'
        WHEN Cust. Order_ID in ('154','3042000103','3042000099') and Cust. Order_ID in ('30400010112','3042000104') THEN 'BothOrders'
END as Orders
From Customer as Cust
GROUP BY Cust.Cust_ID
```

This is not working because it's not returning 'BothOrders' for customers who has either of the 'PreOrder' and either of the 'PostOrder' numbers. The
values in Order's column is (154,3042000103, 3042000099, 30400010112, 3042000099).

I'm expecting something like this...
[image]

But I'm getting...
[image]

Comment: Please show us the data you are working with, as tabular text. We would probably need to see the content of this `order_id` column, along with the result you want.

Comment: this is not a valid query, there's no Cust relation in the FROM clause... because there's no FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine if each customer has a *unique* group of order types.

You can't evaluate this with a simple case expression, even if the order of the evaluation was correct, since you need to evaluate *all* a customer's rows; another way you can approach this is to first define your two possible groups and then evaluate if they are the same for a customer, such as:

```
with t as (
  select *, 
    case when order_id in ('30400010112','3042000104')  then 'Post' else 'Pre' end type
  from Customer 
)
select distinct CustId, 
  case when min(type) over(partition by CustId)
       = max(type) over(partition by CustId) then type else 'Both' 
  end as Orders
from t;
```

Comment: This ended up working for me once I accounted for the null values other wise the nulls was being assigned 'both' as well.

Comment: Good to hear. Nulls weren't a factor of your sample data but yes can easily factor nulls out with a more explicit case expression.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is you need to reorder the `WHEN` conditions to list `Both Orders` first. The `CASE` expression stops evaluating after the first match.

The second issue the `Cust.Cust_ID` is a single value, and it's not possible to have a single `Cust_ID` be both `154` and `30400010112` at the same time. But I can't tell you how to fix this, because I can't see the rest of the query or data.

The third issue is there's no `FROM` clause in the query, so the database doesn't know what table to look at.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I edit with the Customer table. I was a typ. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in your code

```
WHEN Cust. Order_ID in ('154','3042000103','3042000099') and Cust. Order_ID in ('30400010112','3042000104') THEN 'BothOrders’
```

'BothOrders’ quotes don't match, instead try 'BothOrders' like:

```
WHEN Cust. Order_ID in ('154','3042000103','3042000099') and Cust. Order_ID in ('30400010112','3042000104') THEN 'BothOrders'
```

Comment: There are 5 total order ids that can represent a PreOrder or PostOrder  number. The first statement has 3 numbers that can represent a PreOrder numbers  and the second statement has the 2 number that can represent a PostOrder number.

Comment: Yours and mine is identical isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is the single quote at the end of 'BothOrder'  the character ' at the end doesn't evaluate to a single quotation mark

Answer (score 1):

Making a few assumptions...

```
with
    cust as (
        select 
            cust_id,
            case when order_id in ('154','3042000103','3042000099') then 1 else 0 end as pre_order,
            case when order_id in ('30400010112','3042000104') then 1 else 0 end as post_order
        from
            Customer
    )
select
    cust_id,
    case 
        when sum(pre_order) > 0 and sum(post_order) > 0 then 'BothOrders'
        when sum(post_order) > 0 then 'PostOrder'
        when sum(pre_order) > 0 then 'PreOrder'
        else null
    end as orders
from 
    cust
group by
    cust_id
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this and the bothorders clause is not working.